# git-multimail exclude git diff and subsequent emails

Tags: git, gitolite

I am attempting to use git-multimail with gitolite to email users of updates - it was fairly straightforward to set up following the instructions https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail/blob/master/doc/gitolite.rst but I do not want multiple emails to be sent on push, only 1 summary email that appears in the same vein as

```
git log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %ae' --abbrev-commit --date=relative 2da4f6e7..418b7f1b
```

I have tried a number of things, but my current `git config --list` looks like

```
multimailhook.logopts=--pretty=format:"%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %ae"
multimailhook.commitemailformat=html
multimailhook.announceshortlog=true
multimailhook.refchangeshowlog=true
```

The email is sent via html (colors come through), but none of the formatting is coming through - nothing I have tried has made any difference in the email content, nor quantity of emails that are sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send just one summary (*refchange*) email you need to stop `multimail` to send commit emails. To configure this you need to [disable `multimailhook.commitList`](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail#configuration): set it to `none` or an empty string:

```
git config multimailhook.commitList none
```

Comment: This works, thanks - it would be nice if I could stylize the email in the way that the pretty format does, but I can see from the code/comments that the HTML formatting that exists is just a hack. At least I'm now seeing the content I want.